# How to recover NTFS volumes after accidentally formatting drive as JHFS+ volume?

Tags: macos, data-recovery, windows

I was reinstalling 10.9 Mavericks on my dual boot setup.
I had 2 separate HDDs for 2 OS, both Hitachi 500 GB. But i accidentally formatted the Windows 8 HDD (NTFS) to Mac extended journaled.

I had really important files on it.
The disk had 3 partition (the 1st for Windows files, 2nd one was for my work files and the 3rd partition was for other files)

I need to recover everything or at least the work partition

How can i do this?

Comment: How did you format the disc? One big JHFS+ volume? Did you install anything on the accidentally formatted drive?

Comment: If the files are really important, just recover from your backup.

Comment: 1 single volume and did not write a single bit after that.

Comment: I take backup at end of each month. But i had some projects running for this month and dont have backup of those files. Its a 1200$ project which was almost done

Answer (score 1):

I started writing up a long complex answer on how to recover your data using tools like Disk Utility to create a backup image and testdisk to recover the partition table, because that might be all you need to do.

But if you don't already have experience doing work like this and this data is valuable to you, you should really go to a data recovery specialist. At the moment this might be a simple fix, but a wrong step could make this much more complex.

**Please find a local data recovery specialist and ask them to recover your data.**

Comment: Hey there, thanks. But there is only one company providing this service and they charge about 12$ per 1GB :(